# Mouse Event on inner jpanel placed on another jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent

I have one JPanel container in the background, which will move on mouse drag.

I have small inner jpanels placed on different parts of the background container. On each inner jpanels i have a line drawn on it. I want to show a menu only when they click on the lines in the inner panel, clicking on other places in the inner panel should be forwarded to the background panel.

Please help me how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/09/a_wellbehaved_g.html) to understand how to work with glasspane.
But I would draw lines directly on the main panel rather than multiple inner ones. For the lines you can create list of `Shapes` to be drawn. For each the `Shape` (Line) you can create a thick like (use `BasicStroke` with desired thickness) and detect click by asking the stroked line whether it contains the click coordinates.

Comment: But i am working on already developed application, Some inner panels placed on each other. So i want to transfer the click or mouse events to the under placed panels.